# implicit declaration of function that should not be?

Tags: c, typedef

I am working with structs and typedef with an external file that works locally but on automatic checker I get implicit declaration of function ‘gcd’

this code consists of a couple functions that do basic stuff like return sums etc. A function gcd which was handed to us and counts the greatest common divisor and both of these codes/snippets are #included in a different main.c:
   `#include "fraction.h"` `#include "fraction.c"`

```
/* Reduce fraction */
void reduceFraction(Fraction *val) {
    unsigned int fr = gcd(val->numerator, val->denominator);
    val->numerator = val->numerator / fr;
    val->denominator = val->denominator / fr;
}
```

And this is the gcd which works

```
unsigned int gcd(unsigned int u, unsigned int v)
{
    // simple cases (termination)
    if (u == v)
        return u;

    if (u == 0)
        return v;

    if (v == 0)
        return u;

    // look for factors of 2
    if (~u & 1) // u is even
    {
        if (v & 1) // v is odd
            return gcd(u >> 1, v);
        else // both u and v are even
            return gcd(u >> 1, v >> 1) << 1;
    }

    if (~v & 1) // u is odd, v is even
        return gcd(u, v >> 1);

    // reduce larger argument
    if (u > v)
        return gcd((u - v) >> 1, v);

    return gcd((v - u) >> 1, u);
}
```

the error that appears is:
implicit declaration of function ‘gcd’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

Comment: `gcd` is called inside `reduceFraction`. Is there a declaration of `gcd` somewhere before the definition of `reduceFraction`?

Comment: @Angew it might be that I'm missunderstanding your question but as far as the code I'm returning to the checker there is not. the function gcd is only used in `reduceFraction` and how it is called in the main function I do not know, thats up for the automatic checker

Comment: The C language was created at a time when a compiler making multiple passes over an input file was expensive, so it expects you to do the work of describing each function before it's used, either by putting them in the proper order or by using prototypes.

Comment: @vNdong That is the problem, then, as you're calling a function which was not declared (so you're relying on its implicit declaration, as the warning says). [IronMan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56996794/1782465) explains it too.

Comment: That's an unorthodox algorithm for the GCD — Euclid discovered or invented a better one back in c 300 BC.

Comment: This question lacks a [mre]. Voting to close

Answer (score 4):

The warning is telling you that the function was not declared before being used. The function will be assumed to return an int with no restrictions on the type or number of parameters. You can eliminate this warning and enforce better type checking of this function by declaring the function in an included header file or earlier in the module:

```
unsigned int gcd(unsigned int u, unsigned int v);
```